# Pass table name and date as parameters to stored procedure to delete rows with where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures, parameters

```
create PROC usp_delete_qu (
@table NVARCHAR(128),
@new_date datetime) AS BEGIN

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
-- construct SQL
SET @sql = N'delete FROM ' + @table + N' where modified_date < ' +@new_date
-- execute the SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

I create a stored procedure which I need to delete rows with modified date. But while I tried to execute this I got error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_query, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 19]
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My intention is to use this stored procedure to delete rows in all tables in my database.

Comment: Thats a very dangerous stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a parameter in your dynamic statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_delete_qu
   @table NVARCHAR(128),
   @new_date datetime
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
   DECLARE @rc int

   -- construct SQL
   SET @sql = N'delete FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + N' where modified_date < @new_date'

   -- execute the SQL
   EXEC @rc = sp_executesql @sql, N'@new_date datetime', @new_date
   IF @rc <> 0 PRINT 'Error'
END
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to convert your date into string when using dynamic query.

```
create PROC usp_delete_qu (
@table NVARCHAR(128),
@new_date datetime) AS BEGIN

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
-- construct SQL
SET @sql = N'delete FROM ' + @table + N' where modified_date < ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @new_date) + ''' '
-- execute the SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

Comment: the correct way is to use `sp_executesql` with parameter

Comment: What would happen here if this was passed for `@table`: `dbo.MyTable; DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;--`?

Comment: Well, I tried it and it worked, perhaps you should review your procedure ... you can take the idea from here and optimize your code.

Comment: In truth, Zeina, it's you that needs to review this. Injection is still a huge problem in the industry, but there's so few excuses anymore for having it in your code when there so much resource available now on how to avoid it, and the consequences of having it. Ignorance isnt an excuse.